# Debug C# code without running the application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I'm often in the need of debugging/testing my code or a small part of it.

One way to go is of course to run the application I am developing, or when developing a class library creating a small test application.

Another way is to create a unit test just for debugging purpose and run it in Visual Studio.

But what if when I don't want to write additional code (like disposable unit tests) and I don't want to start the whole application (takes some time to start and to navigate to the code I want to debug)?

Is there a way to run a small portion of code in Visual Stuio respectively interpret C# code?

**EDIT**

I know about [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/).

But sometimes I want to know e.g. how an `Form` looks like while running or if a component is able to talk to a database. So LINQPad does not suit my needs in those cases...

Comment: This can be tricky if the code is dependent on other code. For really small independent fragments, why not create a command-line project from scratch and copy-and-paste the code there?

Comment: You can use the QuickWatch option in visual studio. If you want to test a few different statements in the same code put a breakpoint in the position and open quickwatch window. you can find the result of the statement by writing it on the quickwatch window.

Comment: It's a separate project ? or a portion in a whole project ?

Comment: **PowerShell**; it is installed by default on all Windows OS's and it uses .NET natively. You can instantiate any C# object from PowerShell. `using System.IO.File;` is the same as `[System.IO.File]` for example

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use linqpad http://www.linqpad.net/ for quick testing of c# code.

Comment: I was just using it to do some serious string manipulation that would have taken an age to get to in my application - it is awsome!

Comment: The free version doesn't include intellisense, but if you are copying code out of VS it shouldn't matter.. however its worth every penny for the full version :) (not affiliated, just a happy customer)

Comment: Yeah, I know and use linqpad. But you can't e.g. show a `Windows.Form` for debugging purpose...

Comment: @Rhenser You actually can show a Form in LINQPad. You just need to add a refence to System.Windows.Form. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222009/how-does-linqpad-reference-other-classes-e-g-books-in-the-linq-in-action-sampl) to see how to add references. Maybe that's your problem.

Comment: @dkson OK, I didn't know you could add refences to your code in LINQPad. Is it a new feature? It's actually a long time ago since I used LINQPad...

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to download the latest [Roslyn community preview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/roslyn), and have at it with the [C# Interactive Window](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2012/01/30/roslyn-ctp-introduces-interactive-code-for-c.aspx).  It's pre-release software, so it doesn't support the entire C# feature set, but it's getting pretty close.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/). It's super for trying out snippets of code. Don't be put off by the name, it has support for C#/F# programs and expressions.

Answer (score 2):

Another option for quick testing is [Scratchpad.cs](http://kozmic.pl/2012/01/18/testing-framework-is-not-just-for-writing-tests/). Often it is better than creating command line projects just to try an idea.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [F# interpreter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233175.aspx).

I use it regulary to test small code samples.

Let's say you have some code like this:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    public class Test
    {
        public Int32 Sum(int a, int b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Fire up the F# Interactive window, add a referece to your assemblies, and start debugging!

```
> #I @"C:\PathToYourProject\bin\debug";;
--> Added .... to library include path
> #r "ConsoleApplication5.exe";;
--> Referenced ...
> let t = ConsoleApplication5.Test();;
val t : ConsoleApplication5.Test
> t.Sum(9, 7);;
val it : int = 16
>
```

Comment: Ha, this works quite well! I did a quick test with a dynamically created/populated Form I am currently debugging, and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Actually believe it or not, PowerShell uses the .NET framework. You can call any built-in C# class from PowerShell.

Let's say you're trying to test the `String.Substring` method.

Open PowerShell

Then to call the function type this:

```
"some string".Substring(2,1) # returns 'm'
```

Or let's say you want to test a more complicated built-in class

```
foreach($line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines("C:\path\to\file.txt"))
{
     $line
}
```

`[System.IO.File]` is the same thing as saying `using System.IO.File;`

The beautiful thing about PowerShell - *it is C#'s console*... and nobody knows it.